# Content Rating Widget using XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have created some solution for content rating in our websites using XSLT. User is allowed to rate whether he likes the article or not. by clicking yes or no. I want to somehow avoid the user giving multiple feedbacks for the same article. I thought of handling it in Database by using sessionid and ip address but that would create unnecessary space in DB. I want to filter the request before its been sent to DB itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid DB if you are aiming a perfect solution. You could use for example cookies or any kind of session variables to store the necessarry information, but that's not enough: user can delete cookies or log into your application from multiple computers. If you want to prepare for every situation like this you need the information retain over sessions: DB is the solution.